# Facebook Graph API - empty JSON array for public albums of non-friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook's documentation states "To read an Album you need... Any valid access_token if it is public". See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

I'm calling this URL: [https://graph.facebook.com/${user_id}/albums?access_token=${token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%24%7Buser_id%7D/albums?access_token=%24%7Btoken%7D)
When I call the URL above with a user id of a friend, I get a list of albums, but when I call it with a non-friend user id I get an empty array, although I can confirm that the user's albums are public (I can view these albums in Facebook).

Is the documentation incorrect? Did I misunderstand something? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure this profile is public ?
Being able to view user's album on facebook doesn't mean it's public, it can be a second tier friend.

Comment: Thank you, but I confirmed with users that are not in my second tier. I'm able to browse their albums in facebook, but when using the API, I get an empty array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from the context, but it sounds like you're trying to access the album of a user, who is not a friend of the current user. This is not supported via the API.

The three types of photo access which are supported (listed in the [Album documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/)) are:

- The albums belonging to a Page,if they're public-visible, using any access token
- The user's own albums, using the user_photos [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
- The user's friends' albums, using the friends_photos [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

Comment: This what I want (i.e. getting someone's album who isn't a friend). Is this not supported via the API even if the albums are public (i.e. can be seen by non-friends and non-friends-of-friends within the facebook website)?

Comment: No, the API only supports accessing the photos data of your users and their friends, not of unconnected users